# Inconsistent behavior when sorting multi-dimensional arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays that I'm trying to alter and then sort with two similar but different methods. One is coming out correctly, and the other one isn't.

array #1:

```
var scale = [
    [["C","C"], 1],
    [["D","D"], 2],
    [["E","E"], 3],
    [["F","F"], 4],
    [["G","G"], 5],
    [["A","A"], 6],
    [["B","B"], 7],
]
```

array #2:

```
var scale = [
    [["C","C"], 1],
    [["D","D"], 2],
    [["Eb","Eb"], 3],
    [["F","F"], 4],
    [["G","G"], 5],
    [["Ab","Ab"], 6],
    [["Bb","Bb"], 7],
]
```

I'm using this method to sort:

```
this.sortScale = function (a,b) {
    a = a[1];
    b = b[1];
    return a == b ? 0 : (a < b ? -1 : 1);
}
```

That method is then plugged into another method for each array.

For the first array:

```
this.relativeMinor = function(scale) {
    for (var counter = 3; counter <=9; counter++) {
        if (counter > 7) {
            scale[counter - 3].splice(1, 1, counter - 7);
        } else {
            scale[counter - 3].splice(1, 1, counter);
        }
    }
    scale.sort(this.sortScale);
    console.log(scale);
    return scale;
};
```

And for the second array:

```
this.relativeMajor = function(scale) {
    for (var counter = 0; counter <=6; counter++) {
        if (counter > 1) {
            scale[counter].splice(1, 1, counter - 1);
        } else {
            scale[counter].splice(1, 1, counter + 6);
        }
    }
    scale.sort(this.sortScale);
    console.log(scale);
    return scale;
};
```

I want array #1 to come out like this, and it's working:

array #1:

```
var scale = [
    [["A","A"], 1],
    [["B","B"], 2],
    [["C","C"], 3],
    [["D","D"], 4],
    [["E","E"], 5],
    [["F","F"], 6],
    [["G","G"], 7],
]
```

I want array #2 to come out like this, and it's NOT working:

```
var scale = [
    [["Eb","Eb"], 1],
    [["F","F"], 2],
    [["G","G"], 3],
    [["Ab","Ab"], 4],
    [["Bb","Bb"], 5],
    [["C","C"], 6],
    [["D","D"], 7],
]
```

Instead it comes out like this:

```
var scale = [
    [["Ab","Ab"], 4],
    [["Bb","Bb"], 5],
    [["C","C"], 6],
    [["D","D"], 7],
    [["Eb","Eb"], 1],
    [["F","F"], 2],
    [["G","G"], 3],
]
```

What am I missing?

Note: only one of the two methods ever gets called at a given time in my program (scale is created uniquely with one keypress for relative Major, and with a different keypress for relative Minor), so I don't think it's an issue of using "scale" for both `this.relativeMinor` and `this.relativeMajor`.

Comment: Off topic, but curious to know why you're using `.splice()` here instead of just `scale[counter][1] = counter - 1;`

Comment: I notice that in case 2 you're outputting the array before sorting, while in case 1 you're outputting it after sorting.

Comment: I have a feeling your issue is `this` related. If your `this` is not what you expect, you're probably passing `undefined` to `.sort()`, which will make it sort the `.toString()` versions of the Arrays. Your code works for me if the actual sorter is used.

Comment: oops! true, thanks. that's a misplaced line, but the output listed above is from before I misplaced the line, so it's still giving me the wrong array after sorting.

Comment: So in the `.relativeMajor` method, do `console.log("SORTER", this.sortScale + "");` to see what you get.

Comment: You're right—this.sortScale is undefined. Same in the `.relativeMinor` method. For some reason, the `.relativeMinor` method works and the `.relativeMajor` method doesn't. If I include the `sortScale` (not `this.sortScale`) method within `.relativeMinor` and `.relativeMajor`, I get the correct results both times. Thanks! But is there a way to do it without repeating the sortScale code in both methods?

Comment: Also, to answer your first question about `.splice()`—I'm not actually sure. Your way is probably better but I didn't think of it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally don't recommend modifying your original arrays in code like this. Instead, copy them and work on the copies. Or is there a reason you need to modify the originals?

Also, instead of duplicating the code in your two methods, you can write one method that handles both cases with a parameter that specifies the starting scale number.

And you don't need to do any sorting at all! Just write a new array with the elements in the order you want.

I'm going to write this as ordinary functions for easy testing in the browser console; you can make the appropriate changes to make them methods.

```
var majorScaleC = [
    [["C","C"], 1],
    [["D","D"], 2],
    [["E","E"], 3],
    [["F","F"], 4],
    [["G","G"], 5],
    [["A","A"], 6],
    [["B","B"], 7],
];

var minorScaleC = [
    [["C","C"], 1],
    [["D","D"], 2],
    [["Eb","Eb"], 3],
    [["F","F"], 4],
    [["G","G"], 5],
    [["Ab","Ab"], 6],
    [["Bb","Bb"], 7],
];

// Return a relative scale based on an existing scale and starting
// at a specified scale number.
// Note that the scale numbers start at 1, and array indices at 0.
function relativeScale( scaleFrom, start ) {
    var scaleTo = [];
    for( var i = 0;  i < scaleFrom.length;  ++i ) {
        scaleTo.push([
            scaleFrom[ ( i + start - 1 ) % scaleFrom.length ][0],
            i + 1
        ]);
    }
    return scaleTo;
}

function relativeMinor( minorScale ) {
    return relativeScale( minorScale, 6 );
};

function relativeMajor( majorScale ) {
    return relativeScale( majorScale, 3 );
};

console.log( JSON.stringify( relativeMinor(majorScaleC) ) );
console.log( JSON.stringify( relativeMajor(minorScaleC) ) );
```

This logs:

```
[[["A","A"],1],[["B","B"],2],[["C","C"],3],[["D","D"],4],[["E","E"],5],[["F","F"],6],[["G","G"],7]]

[[["Eb","Eb"],1],[["F","F"],2],[["G","G"],3],[["Ab","Ab"],4],[["Bb","Bb"],5],[["C","C"],6],[["D","D"],7]]
```

Comment: I definitely could write out all the major and minor scale arrays, but I'm trying to keep my program length down, so I have a function that calculates and returns major and minor scales from a larger array of all 12 possible notes, and then the relative minor and relative major functions to calculate those scales from their respective major and minor base scales. Is it better just to hard code all the arrays? It seems like so much more code!

Comment: Oh no, of course you can continue to generate the major and minor scales like that - much better than hard coding them! You can still use these functions regardless of how you generate the input arrays, simply pass in the appropriate scale array. I just used two separate input arrays for ease of testing.

Comment: It works! Thanks! I will definitely try to default to making copies as well.